# How to access OSX Services/Keyboard Shortcuts in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Emacs will recognize standard OSX shortcuts like Command + Q, but when I try to do something like open Safari (don't judge me :-P) using my custom shortcut Command + Control + S, the mini buffer says " is undefined."

Is there a way for me to set an Emacs shortcut to be one of the global services/shortcuts that I've defined in OSX?

(OSX 10.9.1, Emacs 24.3)

Comment: The answer is going to be different depending upon whether you are using this setting:  `(setq ns-auto-hide-menu-bar t)`  Are you using that setting?  I'm not sure when it was first introduced, but it makes executing OSX native keyboard shortcuts impossible absent some extraordinary measures.  Please also verify that you are using the standard System Preferences keyboard shortcuts, and not some third-party solution like KeyboardMaestro or something else.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not using that setting.  I've never put it in my init file and it isn't there now.  Also, I'm using custom keyboard shortcuts, but they've been customized through the standard System Preferences options.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not use a system wide keyboard shortcut, but instead uses an applescript:

```
(defun safari-activate ()
(interactive)
  (let ((script (concat
      "tell application \"Safari\"\n"
      "activate\n"
      "end tell")))
    (start-process "safari-activate" nil "osascript" "-e" script)))
```

And here is a slightly different method, but along the same lines:

```
(defun safari-activate-two ()
(interactive)
  (do-applescript "tell application \"Safari\" to activate"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Services Key combination worked when running emacs without customization.

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs.sh --no-init-file
```

After much trial and error discovered that my woes were caused by customization of mac-option-modifier, as per [mac-switch-meta](https://gist.github.com/railwaycat/3498096).
If I switch back or leave it at the default value then I can access the services but the standard shortcuts no longer work! :-(

What's more I was unable to run the service by manipulating the menu as discussed in discussion [No Menu Bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007846/cocoa-application-contains-no-menu-bars-according-to-applescript/28251859#28251859)